# scale and rotation Template matching in opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I want to use a template image to search target in the another image.But the target have scale and rotation change,also the target mix with noise which the color is same with target.
Just like the pic as follow
[image]
I want to get the target by using a ellipse not rectangle.Like the pic2.

How can i do that.I try to use matchtemplate function, but the result is not good.Also,I had tried to use matchShapes() to do that,but the function need to input two contours to compare.As the target is mixed with noise,the coutour from target image is not a coutour what i need.I have no idea.Can you help me and give me some advice?Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: You could try higher level description of the feature, since higher level descriptions can be much easier to match, but then, to obtain the higher level description in the first place you may be into this very problem again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Generalized Hough Transform (GHT), to find contours using template. As I remember, there was ready to use implementation in opencv (gpu) examples.(opencv/samples/gpu/generalized_hough.cpp on my machine)

Here is also useful link with source code: http://www.itriacasa.it/generalized-hough-transform/instructions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate scale and rotation invariant features. There exist several feature descriptors that claim these properties. Scale invariance is often emulated by matching against a set of different scales of the target. Another way can be to normalize scale and rotation of the target first.

Have a look here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/scale-and-rotation-invariant-feature-descriptors

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i think use features is diffcult to get the yellow circle.